# How to temporary replace the main-scroll with inner div scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

[image: My landing page]

this page is contains of main sroll that will scroll whole page and section scroll 1 that will scroll section 1, in this case, the main scroll will stop scrolling when reach section 1 and will continue after section 1 finish scrolled. it means, main scroll will temporary replaced by section 1 scroll when section 1 is on the top of the window, can anybody help me to fix this?? I recently found sticky-kit by leafo but I think this plugin cant resolve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        $('#wrapper').stop().animate({
            scrollTop : $(this).scrollTop()
        });            
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    padding:0;
}

body {
    height:3000px;
}

#wrapper {

    height:300px;
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:100px;
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/c3eAa/184/)

Comment: thanks for your fast respond, but I dont want its position fixed sir.

Comment: please check it my Updated Demo @ronydavid

Comment: thank you sir, but the problem is, the main scroll should be not scrollable till that inner scroll finish scrolled,.

Comment: I just found this

http://webpop.github.io/jquery.pin/

I think I can hold the section using this js and give some jquery code to replace the main scroll temporary. thank you sir